# What's the meaning of "each CPU instruction can manipulate 32 bits of data"?

Tags: c++, c, cpu-registers

From: https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/R/register.html

> The number of registers that a CPU has and the size of each (number of bits) help determine the power and speed of a CPU. For example a 32-bit CPU is one in which each register is 32 bits wide. Therefore, **each CPU instruction can manipulate 32 bits of data.**

What's the meaning of "each CPU instruction can manipulate 32 bits of data" w.r.t the C/C++ programs which we write, the text which we write in notepads?

Comment: "Text which we write in notepads" would not necessarily need 32-bit processing. The real gain is in being able to directly address a huge amount of memory and to do integer calculations with less instructions. (Both were already possible with lesser CPUs; neither are *required* for a menial task such as plain text editing in a Notepad-like application.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First; "each CPU instruction can manipulate 32 bits of data" is a (technically incorrect) generalisation. For example (32-bit 80x86) there are instructions (e.g. `cmpxchg8b`, `pushad`, `shrd`) and entire extensions (MMX, SSE, AVX) where an instruction can manipulate more than 32 bits of data.

For performance; it's best to think of it as either "amount of work that can be done in a fixed amount of time" or "amount of time to do a fixed amount of work". This can be broken into 2 values - how many instructions you need to do an amount of work and how many instructions can be executed in a fixed amount of time (instructions per second).

Now consider something like adding a pair of 128-bit integers. For a 32-bit CPU this has to be broken down into four 32-bit additions, and might look something like this:

```
    ;Do a = a + b

    mov eax,[b]
    mov ebx,[b+4]
    mov ecx,[b+8]
    mov edx,[b+12]
    add [a],eax
    adc [a+4],ebx
    adc [a+8],ecx
    adc [a+12],edx
```

In this case "how many instructions you need to do an amount of work" is 8 instructions.

With a 16-bit CPU you need more instructions. For example, it might be more like this:

```
    mov ax,[b]
    mov bx,[b+2]
    mov cx,[b+4]
    mov dx,[b+6]
    add [a],ax
    mov ax,[b+8]
    adc [a+2],bx
    mov bx,[b+10]
    adc [a+4],cx
    mov cx,[b+12]
    adc [a+6],dx
    mov dx,[b+14]
    add [a+8],ax
    adc [a+10],bx
    adc [a+12],cx
    adc [a+14],dx
```

In this case "how many instructions you need to do an amount of work" is 16 instructions. With the same "instructions per second" a 16-bit CPU would be half as fast as a 32-bit CPU for this work.

With a 64-bit CPU this work would only need 4 instruction, maybe like this:

```
    mov eax,[b]
    mov ebx,[b+8]
    add [a],eax
    adc [a+8],ebx
```

In this case, with the same "instructions per second", a 64-bit CPU would be twice as fast as a 32-bit CPU (and 4 times as fast as a 16-bit CPU).

Of course the high level source code would be the same in all cases - the difference is what the compiler generates.

Note that what I've shown here (128-bit integer addition) is a "happy case" - I chose this specifically because it's easy to show how larger registers can reduce/improve "how many instructions you need to do an amount of work" and therefore improve performance (at the same "instructions per second"). For different work you might not get the same improvement. For example, for a function that works with 8-bit integers (e.g. `char`) "larger than 8-bit registers" might not help at all (and in some cases might make things worse).

Answer (score 1):

Computers, operating systems, or software programs capable of transferring data 32-bits at a time. With computer processors, (e.g. 80386, 80486, and Pentium) they were 32-bit processors, which means the processor were capable of working with 32 bit binary numbers (decimal number up to 4,294,967,295). Anything larger and the computer would need to break up the number into smaller pieces

Answer (score 0):

A "word" is the size of the basic unit of change.

This CPU, in addition to being a 32 bit CPU, has a 32 bit sized word.  If it was changing an item, unless extra CPU cycles are used, the largest "single" item it can change is one 32 bit value.

This doesn't mean that any 32 bit can be changed with one instruction.  But if the 32 bits are all part of the same word, they may be able to be changed in one instruction.